# Retirar máscara de campo jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, masked-input-plugin

Tenho esse código para colocar máscara no campo:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Agora aqui preciso passar o campo `cnpj($("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val())` sem a máscara. Como eu faço isso?

```
function MontaPesquisa() {

    if ($("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() != "")
        resultado = ({ "cnpj": $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() });
    else
        return;

    alert(resultado);

    $.ajax({

        url: '/Pesquisa/MontaTelaPesquisa',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ pesquisaCnpj: resultado }),
        success: function (data) {

            str += '<label>CNPJ digitado incorretamente!</label>';

            $('#filtroPesquisa').html(str);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }

    });
}
```

Aqui está o erro no Json:

```
$.ajax({

        url: '/Pesquisa/MontaTelaPesquisa',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ pesquisaCnpj: resultado }),
        success: function (data) {
```

Especificamente nessa linha:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ pesquisaCnpj: resultado }),
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Poderia informar qual a biblioteca que está utilizando?

Comment: @pnet, pelo que me parece estás a usar um Plugin, é importante referir isso

Comment: @pnet, qual é o resultado do `alert(resultado);`??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilize com o [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) do [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp).

```
$("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'')
```

ou seja na linha

```
resultado = ({ "cnpj": $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'') });
```

Ele vai trazer pra você somente os números

Comment: A tua solução funciona, mas caso ele pretenda retirar o valor de outra mascara diferente tem de andar sempre com o `replace` atrás, ainda assim solução válida :)

Comment: Não entendi @CesarMiguel ?

Comment: Pelo que me parece, o @pnet tem um Plugin onde adiciona máscaras a partir do `.mask`. Deve ter usado isto: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Eu sei disso ... ele usou jQuery Mask (que pode ser vários) e a solução do replace é ideal nesse caso e em qualquer caso de mascara !!!

Answer (score 2):

Apesar da tua pergunta não estar bem clarificada (informa sempre qual o Plugin que estás a usar), vou tentar ajudar.

Para buscares o valor sem a máscara definida tenta:

```
$("#txtCnpjPesquisa").unmask();
```

Comment: Então, fiz conforme o Cesar me passou: if ($("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() != "")
        resultado = ({ "cnpj": $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").unmask() }); Só que dá erro na passagem do parâmetro para minha controller, o erro é: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Aqui est´pa meu Json: $.ajax({

        url: '/Pesquisa/MontaTelaPesquisa',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ pesquisaCnpj: resultado }),
        success: function (data) {

            alert(2);

Comment: @pnet faz `var varSemMask = $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").unmask(); alert(varSemMask);` e diz me o que dá no `alert`

Comment: Resolvi o erro assim: var resultado = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "cnpj": "' + $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").unmask() + '"}'); porem o que está vindo é um Object object e não o cnpj em si, logo em minha controller está sendo passado Object object e não o cnpj. Carai, falta conhecimento dessa bosta

Comment: Acho melhor retirar a máscara na controller. Vou pesquisar em como fazer isso. Fica mais fácil acho que com jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode remover os caracteres no `client side` com jquery ou em `server side` com PHP:

Jquery:

```
str = $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val();
str = str.replace(/[^\d]+/g,"");
```

PHP:

```
$cnpj = $_POST['txtCnpjPesquisa'];
$cnpj = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $cnpj);
```

Comment: Havia feito pelo code behind e funcionou, mas fazendo pelo javascript acho que no meu contexto é melhor. Validar pelo browser, quase sempre é melhor que no behind, salvo exceções, penso eu.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque uma mascara "limpa" no campo, pegue o valor e depois coloque a máscara real novamente:

```
if ($("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() != "")
    $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99999999999999");
    resultado = ({ "cnpj": $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() });
    $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
else
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando o plugin do Jquery pode usar o cleanVal, usando o unmask você estará removendo a máscara do campo, já o cleanVal você estará retornando o valor do campo sem a máscara, são coisas distintas. Sugiro que faça o teste com os dois e veja o comportamento.

```
 var cnpjPesquisa = $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").cleanVal();
```