# Capturar valor de um text sem a mascara?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input

Tenho um campo text mascarado da seguinte forma:

```
$("#txtnuminic").mask("99999999-9");
```

E estou tentando extrair o conteúdo dele sem a máscara da seguinte forma:

```
valor = $("input[type='text']").get(indice).value;
```

Já sei que preciso utilizar o replace, mas como ficaria ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retirar máscara de campo jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14808/retirar-m%c3%a1scara-de-campo-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Na [documentação](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-the-unmasked-typed-value) diz que você tem que usar `cleanVal()` para obter o valor sem a mascara.

```js
$("#txtnuminic").mask("99999999-9");

$('button').click(function (){
  console.log($('#txtnuminic').cleanVal());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='txtnuminic'/>

<button>Pegar Valor</button>
```

Comment: OK, mas nesse caso não funciona se for através do índice, assim ?

Comment: @Ninja2112 Porque não usar o método da documentação? Não é mais fácil?

Answer (score 0):

Não necessariamente com replace, mas se assim o desejar é como segue

```js
$("#txtnuminic").mask("99999999-9");

$('button').click(function (){
  str = $("#txtnuminic").val();
  str = str.replace(/[^\d]+/g,"");
  console.log (str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='txtnuminic'/>

<button>Pegar Valor</button>
```

> a regex retira tudo o que não for digito

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar o método `cleanVal()`, [vide documentação](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-the-unmasked-typed-value).

Aplicando ao seu exemplo, que usa o `get(indice)` seria assim:

Note que o retorno de `get(indice)` está circundado entre `$()`, isso porque a função `cleanVal` é uma extensão de elementos jQuery e o retorno de `get()` não é um elemento jQuery.

```js
$("#txtnuminic").mask("99999999-9");

$('button').click(function (){
  let val = $($("input[type='text']").get(0)).cleanVal();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='txtnuminic'/>

<button>Pegar Valor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em uma linha:

```
valor = $("input[type='text']").get(indice).value.toString().replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
```